# How to set value of list<String> in DynamicJasper

Tags: list, field, dynamic-jasper

I need to generate dynamic count of columns in me report. So I set to my JasperPrint the massive of Object:

```
Object[] obj = new Object[selectedUsers.size()];
//fill the massive
JasperPrint jp = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(dr, new ClassicLayoutManager(), new JRBeanArrayDataSource(obj));
```

My obj is a class:

```
public class ResultsDTO {
    private String login;
    private Integer id;
    private List<String> list;
    private Object[] results;

    public Object[] getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(Object[] results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    public ResultsDTO(){

    }

    public ResultsDTO(Integer id,String login) {
        super();
        this.login = login;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ResultsDTO(String login, Integer id, List<String> list) {
        super();
        this.login = login;
        this.id = id;
        this.list = list;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void addToList(String day_result){
        this.list.add(day_result);
    }
}
```

and then I try to create columns:

```
FastReportBuilder firstReport = new FastReportBuilder();
List<AbstractColumn> column_list = new ArrayList<AbstractColumn>();

AbstractColumn columnId = getColumn("id", Integer.class,"№", 30, headerStyle, detailStyle);
AbstractColumn columnLogin = getColumn("login", String.class,"ФИО", 150, headerStyle, detailStyle);

for (int i = 0; i < header.size(); i++){
    AbstractColumn column = getColumn("results", Object.class, header.get(i), 80, headerStyle, detailStyle);
    column_list.add(column);
}
```

Eventually I have an exception:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report
>   design not valid : 
>      1. Class "java.lang.Object" not supported for text field expression.

Please, help! I don' know how to use jasper and list or array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasper Reports does not allow Object as a valid type for its elements. I has to be one of the following:

- String
- Number (or any subclass of it)
- Date
- Boolean

You should ask each element in the form for its class and pass proper class to the column builder.